# i want to do encrypt & decrypt in flutter using my previous code

Tags: flutter, encryption

i have encrypt & decrypt function on my another project. here is the function :

```
    public static function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
        $output = false;

        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $secret_key = 'R4haSIA';
        $secret_iv = 'r$h4sia';

        $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

        if ($action == 'encrypt') {
            $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
            $output = base64_encode($output);
        } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
            $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

what i want to do is, do the same encrypt & decrypt function in my flutter project with my previous function above. i've tried this, but it doesnt work.

```
  String encryptPassword(String password) {
    final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('R4haSIA');
    final iv = encrypt.IV.fromUtf8('r\$h4sia12345678'); // Panjang IV 16 byte
    final encrypter =
        encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key, mode: encrypt.AESMode.cbc));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(password, iv: iv);

    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  Future<void> _login() async {
    var url = Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/config/db/login.php");
    var pass_enkripsi = encryptPassword(passwordController.text);
    var response = await http.post(url, body: {
      "username": usernameController.text,
      "password": pass_enkripsi,
    });
    var datauser = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (datauser != '') {
      print('Login Success');

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const homepage()),
      );
    } else {
      print('Login failed');
      //print('Login Failed');
      // Navigator.push<void>(
      //   context,
      //   MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      //     builder: (BuildContext context) => MyApp2(),
      //   ),
      // );
    }
  }
```

this is the error message when i ran the code in flutter :

```
I/AssistStructure( 9703): Flattened final assist data: 384 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
E/flutter ( 9703): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Initialization vector must be the same length as block size
```

Comment: The PHP code has several vulnerabilities: hard-coded key and IV material, fast digest as key derivation, direct use of a hex-encoded string as key... In the Dart code the derivation of key and IV via digest is missing, further bugs possible. If the problem persists after the fix, post test data: plaintext and ciphertext (for already posted key and IV material).